# Using NDMP Device as Storage in Symantec Backup Exec 2012

Tags: backup, network-attached-storage, netapp, symantec, ndmp

In our backup system, a group of servers are being backed up using Symantec Backup Exec 2012 to HP Disk Cartridges.
We use **HP Ultrium 5-SCSI** as the disk drive, and **HP 1x8 G2 Autoloader** to load the disk cartridges.

Sometimes, the writing speed (especially for the mailbox VM backup) can stall the other backup processes, therefore I'm looking out for alternative backup paths.

We have a **NetApp FAS2220** (*Software Version: 8.1.3 7-Mode*) device, that is not currently being used in our backup operations. I would like to include it as a secondary path.

What I'm planning to do is, to use **NDMP Option** of my **Symantec Backup Exec 2012** , which is currently activated for NetApp, thanks to NetApp support staff, but currently I can only take backups **from** my NetApp device, I would like to use it as a storage device, and use it as a secondary tool when our HP disk drive does not have any disk space available.

My NDMP option at **BUE** is also activated, **but** in trial version, I would like to see if I can use it before purchasing it.

Currently I've created an **ndmpuser** from my NetApp, and did *test credentials* on **BUE**, it works fine. What I would like to see is some option like **Backup to NDMP Disk** in the Backup button in the "Backup and Restore" tab, would that be possible?

If not, can you recommend me a NetApp snapshot technology product that would be able to take a snapshot of our mailbox regularly?

Answer (score 0):

Usually we backup NDMP device using Backup exec. NDMP volumes will have data that needs to be backed up to Storage device like Tape or Disk. But if you want to use ndmp as storage then you can have volumes or cifs shares of ndmp mounted on Backup exec server as LUNS with a drive letter. Then you can configure these LUNS as Disk storage on Backup Exec server. Once you have Disk storage configured then you can backup any server to it.